# excel extendable formula for conditional sums over multiple columns

Tags: excel, array-formulas, sumifs

I have an arbitrary number of columns, one for each period a course is offered, in chronological order, and an arbitrary number of rows, one for each unique participant. The values are '1' for participation in that month, '0' for non-participation.

```
Fall2019  Spring2019  Fall2018  Spring2018  Fall2017
1  1  0  1  0
0  1  1  1  1
0  1  1  1  1
0  1  1  1  1
0  1  0  1  1
0  1  1  0  0
0  1  1  0  0
0  1  1  0  0
1  0  0  0  0
```

I would like to take a sum, at the bottom of each column, for how many participants were first time attendees that period, i.e. the sum of '1's where all values in the row to the right of that '1', are '0'. 
In the given example set, Spring2018 should sum to 1, Fall2018 should sum to 3.

Something like the formula below will work for 'Spring2018' when there is just one previous column to compare:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((D2:D9)*(E2:E9=0))
```

But this formula cannot be 'autofilled' or extended across multiple columns... i.e. none of these variations work:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C2:C9)*(D2:$E9=0))
=SUMPRODUCT((C2:C9)*(SUM(D2:$E9)=0))
=SUMPRODUCT((C2:C9)*(SUMIF(D2:$E9,"0")))
```

And while it will work, I do NOT want to have to manually create extended versions of this formula e.g.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C2:C9)*(D2:D9+E2:E9=0))
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B9)*(C2:C9+D2:D9+E2:E9=0))
... and so on
```

I have tried several variations on arrayformula, sumproduct, and sumif, but I'm really stuck. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Nice question, wouldn't having an unknow number of rows be problematic pasting your result on the bottom of each column?

Comment: Good point. In my experience as long as new rows or columns are added in the middle of the range, the formula will adjust to the appropriate range. That's robust enough for my use case, at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this array formula:

```
=SUM(A2:A10*(MMULT(--(B$2:$E$10=1),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B$2:$E$10)^0))=0))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Works brilliantly (I adapted with 'Arrayformula' around it as I am in Google Sheets and not Excel proper). I am unfamiliar with both the COLUMN function, and what "--" is doing inside MMULT so I'll look into that. Thanks for this elegant solution.